# How does Mockito timeout work?

Tags: java, junit, timeout, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and JUnit and try to understand basic unit testing with these frameworks. Most concepts in JUnit and Mockito seem straightforward and understandable. However, I got stuck with `timeout` in Mockito. Does `timeout` in Mockito play the same role as it does in JUnit? Bellow is my code.

```
@Mock Timeoutable timeoutable;

@Test(timeout = 100)
public void testJUnitTimeout() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) { 

    }
}

@Test
public void testMockitoTimeout(){
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){

            }
            return null;
        }
    }).when(timeoutable).longOperation();
    timeoutable.longOperation();
    verify(timeoutable, timeout(100)).longOperation();
}
```

I expected that both tests failed. But only `testJUnitTimeout()` failed. Why does the second test pass?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the value of `timeoutable` in the second method?  Are you certain that the `Thread.sleep(1000)` call is being executed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `timeoutable` is just an mocked object of Timeoutable interface that I wrote out just for testing. No more no less.

Comment: Can you run your unit test in debug mode?  I suspect that the `Thread.sleep()` call is never being executed in the second test.

Comment: I've tried to run in debug mode. The `Thread.sleep()` was actually called as expected. I suspect that the time executing of `doAnswer` and other similar stubbing methods are not taken into timeout count.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question if you have an explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Verification with timeout](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22) is intended to be used to verify whether or not the operation has been invoked **concurrently** within the specified timeout.

It provides a limited form of verification for concurrent operations.

The following examples demonstrate the behaviour:

```
private final Runnable asyncOperation = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            timeoutable.longOperation();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

};

@Test
public void testMockitoConcurrentTimeoutSucceeds(){
    new Thread(asyncOperation).start();
    verify(timeoutable, timeout(2000)).longOperation();
}

@Test
public void testMockitoConcurrentTimeoutFails(){
    new Thread(asyncOperation).start();
    verify(timeoutable, timeout(100)).longOperation();
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, your code works fine with timeout. Can you explain why my code does not work? Thanks

Comment: My code is invoking `timeoutable.longOperation();` in a different thread from the test and yours is not.

Comment: I've just changed your code by putting `timeoutable.longOperation();` before `Thread.sleep(1000)`. Then both tests are passed. Thus, I infer that `verify` actually waits for  `timeout` duration, during that duration if `longOperation()` is called then the test passes. It does not measure how long actually `longOperation()` executes.  Does my inference correct?

Comment: That's right - read the link (which I just fixed) at the beginning of my post

Comment: The [VerificationWithTimeoutTest in Mockito's sources](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/test/java/org/mockitousage/verification/VerificationWithTimeoutTest.java) also illustrates the use the timeout() VerificationWithTimeout VerificationMode nicely.