# Why doesnt the verify( times(n)) doesnt work?

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, powermockito

When i do:

```
verify(authenticatorMock, timeout(1000).times(9)).authenticateUser(username, password);
```

it gives me the following error:

Wanted 9 times: -> at com.mokitoTutorial.app.AuthenticatorApplicationTest.testAuthenticate(AuthenticatorApplicationTest.java:39) But was 1 time: -> at com.mokitoTutorial.app.AuthenticatorApplication.authenticate(AuthenticatorApplication.java:28)

Why only verifies 1 time?

```
@Test
    public void testAuthenticate() {
        AuthenticatorInterface authenticatorMock;
        AuthenticatorApplication authenticator;
        String username = "JavaCodeGeeks";
        String password = "unsafePassword";

        authenticatorMock = Mockito.mock(AuthenticatorInterface.class);
        authenticator = new AuthenticatorApplication(authenticatorMock);

        when(authenticatorMock.authenticateUser(username, password))
                .thenReturn(false);

        boolean actual = authenticator.authenticate(username, password);

        verify(authenticatorMock, timeout(100).times(9)).authenticateUser(username, password);
        System.out.println("wait");

        assertFalse(actual);
    }
```

Comment: Why should it be called 9 times? Apparently there is only a single call to that method in your `AuthenticatorApplication`.

Comment: Im a beginner and im following a tutorial, and im testing the possibilites, when i say i want to verify 9 times shouldnt it verify 9 times?

Comment: No as that isn't what it does. Basically you want to verify if that method has been called 9 times, that is what you verify.

Comment: Oh ok i guess i got that wrong then, but what the timeout acctualy does? i was expecting 9 verifications with a time gap of 100 miliseconds

Comment: Currently you expect it to run max 100 milliseconds and in that timeframe expect 9 calls to `authenticateUser`.

Comment: But even if i put only 1 millisecond, the verification still passes the test

Comment: And why sholdnt it? Does the execution of the method take longer then a millisecond?

Comment: Maybe the processing of the code takes less than 1 millisecond, but the console output of the test takes more than 1 milisecond to appear maybe thats why it is confusing me

Comment: The verify is only considering the single method execution you are checking, eveything else isn't relevant.

Comment: im trying to force the verification to fail by dividing the 1 millesecond by 2137999999, my point is to put a limit so low that the verification fails, is that stupid or what?

Comment: Timeout takes millis so dividing it will not help as it will round to 1 ms. Why do you want it to fail?

Comment: even if i put 0 milliseconds it still passes the test

Comment: like i said i just want to test the possiblities to understand the applications of the  verify( timeout())

Comment: Sorry for being annoying i am just curious about it

Comment: Looking at the documentation you will need another Thread to invoke the methods. `timeout` is used to test concurrent code, hence you need to invoke it in another thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398021/how-does-mockito-timeout-work