# How to create a mock response or simulate socket timeout exception?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, mockito, socket-timeout-exception

I am calling an external api and receiving a runtime exception for socket timeout. Is there a way I can recreate or mock simulate this socket timeout exception by creating a mock response.

Comment: Have you read? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398021/how-does-mockito-timeout-work/31398908

Comment: Yeah looked through. Currently looking to host an API which can simulate this exception.